# Is there any way to know Cordova app crash log

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I already have $exceptionHandler in my Ionic app to log any JS/Angular-specific error.

But if for some reason app crashes completely like if it just closes without any warning then how to know the reason behind the crash?

Comment: Can we know because of which code app crash?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Application Insights](https://github.com/Microsoft/cordova-plugin-ms-appinsights) by Microsoft.

Provides a dashboard wih detailed screen-screen flow , screenshots and app crash logs

*I have used in  my projects with good success rate.*